# como alterar a tabela de users do laravel para uma tabela de usuarios que já existe no meu banco de dados

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, autenticação

Galera eu estou desenvolvendo uma api pelo laravel, porém estou usando um banco de dados já existente que usava uma aplicação pelo codeigniter, preciso usar a tabela de usuários deste banco para fazer login dos usuários, pesquisei bastante coisa sobre isso e tentei fazer, porém não estou conseguindo fazer da certo, não estou conseguindo logar (nem msm eu criando um novo usuario com o padrão de senha do laravel eu consigo fazer login), vou mandar algumas alterações q fiz no código:

O controller para fazer login:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    if (!Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'senha')))
    {
        return response()
            ->json(['message' => 'E-mail ou senha incorretos.'], 401);
    }

    $user = TbUsuario::where('email', $request['email'])->firstOrFail();

    $token = $user->createToken('auth_token')->plainTextToken;

    return response()
        ->json(['message' => 'Oi '.$user->nome.', Acesso autorizado, Bem vindo','access_token' => $token, 'token_type' => 'Bearer', ]);
}
```

alteração no arquivo config/auth.php

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
```

porém quando eu tento fazer login sempre da q o e-mail ou senha está incorreto.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

1º - Você tem duas opções para utilizar, pode utilizar o mesmo model do users que é gerado pelo laravel ou você pode criar um novo model para gerir essa informação. Contudo, caso você use o mesmo model gerado pelo laravel, você precisa informar que aquele model vai servir como base para outra tabela, para isso utilize a variavel dentro do módel `protected $table = "NomedaTabela"`. Na dúvida
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#table-names

2º Considerando que você tenha utilizado o mesmo nome do model gerado pelo laravel e que você já setou qual é o nome da tabela, agora é fácil, mas fazer a autenticação.
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#authenticating-users

3º Contudo, caso não tenha utilizado o model gerado pelo laravel, você precisa ou trocar ou adicionar um novo `GUARD` para que o laravel possa reconhecer ele e você consiga fazer a autenticação
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#adding-custom-guards

Siga esses passos que você vai conseguir fazer a autenticação.

Comment: Vlw Jose, consegui resolver...

Answer (score -3):

O problema parece estar na sua tentativa de autenticação. O método Auth::attempt() espera que os campos de e-mail e senha sejam os padrões do Laravel, ou seja, "email" e "password". No entanto, você está passando "email" e "senha" como parâmetros. Para resolver isso, você precisará alterar o método login() para usar os campos corretos:

```
if (!Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password')))
```

Além disso, você também pode precisar configurar a coluna da tabela de usuários que armazena a senha, para que ela corresponda ao padrão do Laravel. Por padrão, o Laravel espera que a coluna de senhas seja chamada "password", mas no seu caso, parece ser "senha". Você pode configurar isso no seu model User, usando o método setPasswordAttribute():

```
    //no seu UserModel:
    public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['senha'] = bcrypt($value);
    }
```

Essa solução fará com que toda vez que você salvar um usuário, a senha seja encriptada automaticamente.

Se você continuar tendo problemas para fazer login, é possível que a senha armazenada no banco de dados não esteja no formato esperado pelo Laravel. Certifique-se de que as senhas estão sendo armazenadas como hash.

Espero que isso lhe ajude a resolver o problema.

Alguns docs referência:

> Authentication:
> https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#authenticating-users
>
> Mutators:
> https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator